# Typescript / node API with express route error

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am running into a very strange error, I import my router from an external file and go to add it as a route, but I am getting this rather strange error , the string seems to be doubly surrounded with quotes.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

It turned out I was importing the route file incorrectly,

As I was using `export default` in my route file, this meant that when I explicitly imported the file using `import {BlahBlah} from '../some-file.ts'` , I was not importing what I thought. So by removing the braces like `import BlahBlah from '../some-file.ts'` it worked.